# Run API requests sequentially in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, axios

Looking for the best way to accomplish the following.

The goal is to, when this screen loads:

1. Retrieve the user's auth token from async storage, THEN
2. Hit an API with the auth token to grab some user details (in this case userId)

I'm also trying to useEffect so these only run once.

Function 1:

```
const getUserToken = async () => {
      try {
        const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userToken", userToken);
        setUserToken(userToken);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("err retrieving token " + err);
      }
```

Function 2:

```
const getUserId = async () => {
      try {
        let response = await xano.get("/auth/me", {
          headers: { Authorization: userToken },
        });
        setUserId(response.data.id);
        console.log(userId);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("getUserId err " + err);
        console.log(err.data);
      }
    };
```

Function 3:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getUserToken();
getUserId();

  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to await those async functions in the useEffect hook.

```
useEffect(async () => {    
    await getUserToken();
    await getUserId();  
}, [])
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this did not work and had the exact same results as the original code I posted

Comment: @bolsen26 make sure to use async function in useEffect too. I've added it.